# What should be the .htaccess rule for following condition?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I have following links :

http://www.example.com/pdf/this-is-a-link.html

which should convert to :

http://www.example.com/index.php?query=this-is-a-link&type=pdf

Also, .css, .js etc files needs to avoid this rule. My .htaccess file so far is this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(.*)?$ $2/$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html$ index.php?query=$2&type=$1&link=seo [L]

</IfModule>
```

Problem is, now we have an admin panel. The css and js files are falling into into the `^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(.*)?$ $2/$3` rule.
Example of such link: http://www.example.com/admin/css/bbpress.css

How can i modify the rule so that "if it NOT contains the word admin..." ?

Comment: should it be RewriteRule ^(admin)/(.*)?$ $1/$2  [L] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a condition before first rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^admin
```